# nth-last-of-type doesn't work on my div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

demo http://jsfiddle.net/5m38knq7/

I expect to get rid off the last of div's border but it doesn't work?

```
.content-box .item div:nth-last-of-type(1) {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Actually you need to select the last `div.item` element but none of the CSS pseudo classes like `:last-of-type` or `:nth-last-of-type` respects the *class* selector. I.e. they looks through the children tree of the parent to select the valid child element, not the combination of `element.class`

Answer (score 2):

`.content-box .item div:nth-last-of-type(1)` will match the last `div` which is a descendant of the `.item` while you should target the `.item` (because you set border on the `.item`). So it should be: `.content-box div.item:nth-last-of-type(1)`, however note that you have the last div containing the `Top` link, so the correct rule is `.content-box div.item:nth-last-of-type(2)`

### [Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5m38knq7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use last element like this

```
p:last-of-type
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

The :last-of-type selector matches every element that is the last child, of a particular type, of its parent.

Tip: This is the same as :nth-last-of-type(1).

Comment: why does this .content-box .item:last-of-type{
 border: none !important;
}; doesn't work?